# What software tracks the sites I've registered or subscribed to, especially paid subscriptions?

Tags: privacy, password-manager, reminders

**Some background:**

I am moving to a new email address, and I want to delete any accounts tied to my old email address. But I can't remember what I've signed up for. It would be nice to revisit any subscriptions and unsubscribe, download data that I want to preserve, update the email if I plan to keep using the service, etc. But that's actually not what I'm aiming for with this question. I'd much rather just let those old accounts rot. I don't really care if I forgot some or most of them. The important ones are already taken care of.

**The real task at hand:**

Moving forward, I would like to proactively keep track of places I give my email to. And more especially I'd like to keep track of paid subscriptions. I also want to know all the usernames, names, and other personal info I input across various sites.

Must haves:

- Saves the form for signing up and the values I entered into the form.
- Secure.
- Displays all sites I signed up for and the forms I filled out.
- Reminds me when a subscription will renew.
- Reminds me when a trial will end.

Nice to haves:

- If I signed up with Facebook, Google, etc, it saves which method I used and which Facebook (google, etc.) user I logged in with. (I hardly do this anymore)
- Adjustable preferences to save "Welcome" emails and other emails.
- Saves terms and conditions.
- Accumulates ratings about the company and its service from other users.
- Generates knowledge about how to unregister, and lets me see people's reviews about the un-subscribing, un-registering, or account deletion process for that site. This info should be available to me before I sign up for a site.
- Generates knowledge about companies' email campaigns: how often they send email, do they send special discounts, etc. This info should be available to me before I sign up for a site.
- Gives me some type of cryptocurrency each time I use it.
- Increases the value of the internet as a whole.
- Finds me a math tutor.

**OS?** Any.

**Web app, desktop, etc.?** Any.

**Paid or free?** Anything. But I'm not legally capable of being an *accredited investor*

**Open source or not?** Either.

Digging around the internet I found https://knowem.com/ where I can type in my typical usernames and check multiple social media sites for its availability. That's gonna help me after the fact. But I can't find any helpful tools for saving my info when I sign up, and especially for reminding me that a trial is ending. Some companies are nice and tell you themselves. But some aren't. My browser can save a disgusting amount of my personal info and login/password info. But still no reminders of trials ending.

When I was in school, some people I knew had built a tool for this. I am trying so hard to remember what they called it. But I think it only ever reached a beta phase, and I think they all moved on to different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining a password manager, such as KeePass, with a program for managing reminders, such as Lightning, a calendar plugin for Thunderbird. When you sign up for an account, put your username, password, email address, etc. in KeePass and make a reminder for when any subscription or trial ends in Lightning. This gets you all your must-haves, and you'd be hard-pressed to find any software that generates knowledge or finds math tutors, anyway.

Comment: I'm checking those out now. Thanks a ton. I see this as a very proactive effort as well, which is how I imagined it. I plan on accepting this soon once I'm all set up. Do you know if KeePass or Lightning are built for easily integrating with more services? So that I can string together multiple apps to fullfill the other nice to haves and things like that?

Comment: @PieTillIDie I'm not sure. I haven't used these programs much myself. I only really use Thunderbird for email, and I use a ccrypt-encrypted text file for password management.

Comment: There are various plugins for KeePass so it seems it is easy to extend it for more needs.